# Check for existing file

Tags: c#, arrays, file, for-loop, io

I need a way to check whether or not a picture already is in the lbl_Dias. If not add picture, if it is, move to next picture.

This is to make a list of images that is in a random order, but without dublicates.

What I got so far is this

```
protected void DiasShow()
    {
        string[] getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/CSS/Design/Page_Design/Dias/1920x1080/"));

        for (int i = 0; i <= GetFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            Random FindRandom = new Random();
            string RandomFileName = getFiles[FindRandom.Next(getFiles.Length)];

            FileInfo ImageName = new FileInfo(RandomFileName);
            string FileType = ImageName.Name.Substring(ImageName.Name.Length - 4);

            if ((FileType.ToUpper() == ".JPG") || (FileType.ToUpper() == "JPEG"))
            {
                lbl_Dias.Text += "<img src=\"CSS/Design/Page_Design/Dias/1920x1080/" + ImageName.Name + "\" />";
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope you guys can help, i'm kinda stock ^^

Comment: Why is the process to find a file random?

Comment: because i don't want the pictures to be in the same order everytime

Comment: Not clear, where are you checking for the file?

Comment: note: you use loop to count number of images - you can get it just `GetFiles.Length`

Comment: Can `lbl_Dias.Text` assumed to contain no file names before this method is called?

Comment: You can use the `Extension` property in `FileInfo` instead of extracting it with `Substring`

Comment: You now changed the seed (`MilliSecond + count`), but usually you should move the initialisation of the Random instance outside of the loop, to prevent repeated duplicate "random" numbers.

Comment: @weston the label lbl_Dias i empty before the code i executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you just want to list the files in a random order:

```
protected void DiasShow()     
{
    var getFiles = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/CSS/Design/Page_Design/Dias/1920x1080/")); //Find alle filer I en mappe     

    var random = RandomiseList(getFiles);

    var txt = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var randomFileName in random)
    {
        var fileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(randomFileName).ToUpper(); 

        if ((fileType == ".JPG") || (fileType == ".JPEG")) 
        {
           var imageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(randomFileName); 
           txt.Append("<img src=\"CSS/Design/Page_Design/Dias/1920x1080/" + imageName+ "\" />");
        }
    }
    lbl_Dias.Text += txt.ToString();
 }

 public static T[] RandomiseList<T>(T[] source)
 {
     var rand = new Random(); //no need for own seed
     var list = new List<T>(source); //copy to a new list which we can remove from
     var result = new T[source.Length];
     for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
     {
         var listIndex = rand.Next(list.Count());
         result[i]= list[listIndex];
         list.RemoveAt(listIndex);
     }
     return result;
 }
```

Comment: Do you use a System.something for the StringBuilder?

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard It's `System.Text.StringBuilder` or you can put the `using System.Text;` at the top of the file. When you have an unknown item like that hover over it with the mouse and visual studio can often help you fix it.

Comment: Instead of GetFilesWithoutExtension wouldn't it be better to use GetFileName to get the type of file?

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard Yeah, that makes more sence.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, get rid of NumberOfImages, as it's pointless.
The whole foreach-loop is horrible since you're iterating through the collection where it isn't needed.

Secondly, you can use the Extension property of  FileInfo to check for the extension string of a file - no need to substring, etc.

Thirdly, what exactly are you trying to do here?

You do realize that you will probably get random duplicates at the end of the loop, since you are not removing used images from the collection.

In the end, you don't need to check if a file exists at all, since you got it from a function that returns files that exist.

```
protected void DiasShow()
{
    var mapPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/CSS/Design/Page_Design/Dias/1920x1080/");

    var images =
        Directory.GetFiles(mapPath).Select(
            file => new FileInfo(file)).Where(fi =>
                fi.Extension.EndsWith("jpg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                fi.Extension.EndsWith("jpeg", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();

    var rand = new Random();

    while (images.Count > 0)
    {
        var i = rand.Next(images.Count);
        lbl_Dias.Text += "<img src=\"CSS/Design/Page_Design/Dias/1920x1080/" + images[i].Name + "\"/>";
        images.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code where you are checking for the file, I assume you are checking file names.

use [Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) Or [Regex](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) match after extracting out text from lbl_Dias.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of filenames.

each time you assigned a filename you check if it's in the list, if not add it to the list, if it exists look for a different file.

Answer (score 0):

To verify something is not in the text of your label have a corresponding dictionary and check it before adding it to the label such as

```
Dictionary<string, int> _filenames = new Dictionary<string,int>();

....

if (_filenames.ContainsKey( ImageName.Name ) == false)
{
    _filenames.Add(ImageName.Name, 0);

    lbl_Dias.Text += "<img src=\"CSS/Design/Page_Design/Dias/1920x1080/" + ImageName.Name + "\" />"; 

}
```